# Eclipse Oxygen error "Bad Character" at the new C++14 digit separator

Tags: c++, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

`#define FOO 1'000` triggers this Eclipse Oxygen warning:

> Bad character sequence encountered: '000

`gcc 7.3` compiles it of course fine.

I set under *Project* -> *Properties* -> *C/C++ Build* -> *Settings* -> *Dialect* -> *Other dialect flags* the value `-std=c++17`.

What am I missing in order Eclipse does not show this warning? Due to this warning all references using `FOO` are not resolved and this results in other errors displayed by Eclipse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eclipse has its own C++ parser, and it doesn't have complete support for C++14 and C++17 features yet.

[Bug 519062](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=519062) tracks support for C++14 digit separators.